# my computer voice does not work after I reboot or turn off

Tags: sound

well I'm new in ubuntu.

my problem is that when i turn off or reboot my computer, it doesn't play any sound when I play videos or audio files. for that purpose i have to unplug and replug my speakers. its not such a big deal but it kinda goes on my nurves.

thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Your difficulty can be diagnosed most easily from the command line. Are you familiar with commands, filenames, etc? On the command line, keep an eye on `sudo journalctl --follow` while you unplug/replug the speakers.  Compare this with how system startup treats the speakers, as shown by `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. When `sudo` asks for a password, tupe your login password.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].